# Android fails to call SQLite WHERE column LIKE '%?%' The statement has 0 parameters

Tags: android, sqlite, android-contentresolver

With this code

```
public static List<App> findByKeyword(Context context, String keyword){
   ContentResolver resolver = context.getContentResolver();
   Uri uri = getContentUri();
   String[] projection = DataColumns.ALL;
   String selection = DataColumns.NAME+" like '%?%' ";
   String[] selectionArgs = {keyword};
   Cursor cursor = resolver.query(uri, projection, selection, selectionArgs, DEFAULT_ORDER );
   return cursorToList(cursor);
}
```

I get error

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot bind argument at index 1 because the index is out of range.  The statement has 0 parameters.

The SQLite raw query should be `SELECT * FROM table WHERE name LIKE '%?%'`
but there is problem of using parameter though ContentResolver query API

I also tried using `"` quotes

```
String selection = DataColumns.NAME+" like \"%?%\" ";
```

It also says

> The statement has 0 parameters.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try the other way round:

```
String selection = DataColumns.NAME+" like ? ";
String[] selectionArgs = new String[]{ "%"+keyword+"%" };
```

hope it helps