# How can i use Regex to get data from sqlite?

Tags: regex, android-sqlite

I want to search in a column that containing String like "I will have #dinner with @Akki on her #Bday.I am searching now like this but it's note working.
while the variable search having value like #dinner. Thank you.

`selectionArgs =  new String[] {"'"+search+"'"};
        String qur="SELECT * FROM TODOS WHERE fullnote REGEXP";
        Cursor c = db.rawQuery(qur,selectionArgs);`

Comment: Try `String qur="SELECT * FROM TODOS WHERE fullnote LIKE %#dinner%'"`.

Comment: i have to use rawQuery, like am trying. so i have to pass two args in 'rawQuery(query,args);'

Comment: Did you try adding a space after "REGEXP"?

Comment: I tried but same. in debug  There is noting in selectionArgs Cursor c = db.rawQuery(qur,selectionArgs);  while above this search have a value. like #something

Comment: Then try adding `?` (single one as you are passing a 1-item string array): `String qur="SELECT * FROM TODOS WHERE fullnote REGEXP ?"`

Comment: Still same problem. the search variable is not being passed into method db.rawQuery(qur,selectionArgs) in break point it shows the qur's value only

Answer (score -1, accepted):

After long R&D i came to point that i can not  use REGEXP directly. 
then i tried
 `Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM TODOS WHERE tag LIKE '%"+search+"%' ",null);`

and it worked fine.
Thanks everybody.

Answer (score 2):

Try using

```
String[] selectionArgs = new String[] {"%"+search+"%"};
Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM TODOS WHERE fullnote LIKE ?",selectionArgs);
```

See [Android SQLite reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#rawQuery(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[])):

> `public Cursor rawQuery (String sql, String[] selectionArgs)`
>
> `selectionArgs`   - You may include `?`s in where clause in the query, which
>   will be replaced by the values from `selectionArgs`. The values will be
>   bound as Strings.

Comment: can you please create a method with the query() method.

Comment: Please check if you have all names spelt correctly and they are really present. Make sure your *search* is not null.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25932519/android-failes-to-call-sqlite-where-column-like-the-statement-has-0-parame

Answer (score -1):

```
selectionArgs =  new String[] {search};
    Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM TODOS WHERE fullnote LIKE '%?%'",selectionArgs);
```

Comment: Please add some explanation around why this helps

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25932519/android-failes-to-call-sqlite-where-column-like-the-statement-has-0-parame